# Avoid infinite loop after 301 redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I just used a rewrite to remove the file extension .php from the end of all my website pages in my .htaccess file:

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`

The re-write works great, but now when I create a redirect for any page, say contact.php to redirect now to /contact, it creates an infinite loop. I know it's probably a very easy fix but I don't know the language at all enough to write the script. Any help on what I need to do do modify my existing script to avoid the infinite loop would be appreciated!

...There are similar posts on this however, I can't find any that match my situation exactly and since I'm not familiar enough with the technical language, it's hard for me to discern which variables could/should be changed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Yes using `%{THE_REQUEST}` is the right way to get this redirect working +1

Comment: Beautiful! At first I thought it wasn't working since I tried to also create a redirect for the page, but this code also takes care of setting up the redirects for me too! Thanks!!!! :)